# Why is "Environment.CurrentDirectory" set to "C:\\Program Files\\IIS Express"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am following API Gateway example at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-api-gateway-using-ocelot-in-asp-net-core/

And I create an empty asp.net web api application and followed the steps as mentioned in above link.

My Main() function in Program.cs file is:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureServices(s =>
        {
            s.AddSingleton(builder);
        });
        builder.UseKestrel()
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseUrls("http://localhost:9000");

        var host = builder.Build();
        host.Run();
    }
```

Also, my Startup.cs file has following code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
               .AddJsonFile("configuration.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Action<ConfigurationBuilderCachePart> settings = (x) =>
        {
            x.WithMicrosoftLogging(log =>
            {
                log.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

            }).WithDictionaryHandle();
        };
        services.AddOcelot();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        await app.UseOcelot();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get error for file `configuration.json NOT FOUND`.
And when I check the source code for current directory in above functions I see that the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns PATH as `C:\\Program Files\\IIS Express` and not the current project directory.

My question is why is the path set to IIS directory ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`. You can't rely on the current working directory for loading resources since it can be changed at any time.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core 2.2 InPrpcess hosting model?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes

Comment: Check my answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in **ASP.NET Core 2.2** which has been reported in [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206) and Microsoft ASP.NET Core team has provided an solution as follows and they will add this solution in the feature version of ASP.NET Core.

Write a helper class as follows:

```
public class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
{
    internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
    private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct IISConfigurationData
    {
        public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
        public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
        public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
        public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
    }

    public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
            var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
            {
                // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return;
                }

                IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
            }

            Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the `SetCurrentDirectory()` method in the `Main` method as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

     CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory(); // call it here


    IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddSingleton(builder);
    });
    builder.UseKestrel()
           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .UseUrls("http://localhost:9000");

    var host = builder.Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

Now everything should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this out of process until a permanent fix is provided in .net core 3.0.
To change this you can change the setting in the csproj file from

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>inprocess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

to

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>outofprocess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Or if you are running under IISExpress you can set the Hosting Model in the launchsettings.json file. Right click the project file in Visual Studion and Properties -> Debug -> Web Server Setting -> Hosting Model. 
Setting it to Out of Process will add

```
"ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess"
```

to the IIS Express profile in launchsettings.json